# Node-Red UI_Template send msg

Tags: javascript, node-red

to control my robot via Node-Red dashboard, I need some kind of joystick control for UI (not a hardware joystick).

Luckily I found nippleJS which does exactly what I was looking for. Also I was able to get it running with ui_template node.

Now I get stuck. How can I send the coordinates back to node-red node? I know that I can't reach any context and I only get a msg object. But I'm unable to change it (msg undefined).

Here is my current flow. To run it you must load nipplejs and set the path accordingly. I hope someone out there can show me a way how to send data back to node-red

```
[{"id":"ff5f827f.796e","type":"ui_template","z":"9738c4ac.01e748","group":"9550e4e.ea6f618","name":"","order":0,"width":"6","height":"6","format":"\n<script src=\"/myjs/nippleJS/nipplejs.min.js\" ></script>\n\n<div data-type=\"semi\" id=\"zone_joystick\" style=\"position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:grey;\"></div>\n\n<script>\n\n\n           (function(scope){ \n\n                scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {\n                createJoystick();\n           \n                });\n            })(scope);\n\n\nfunction createJoystick(){\n    var semi = nipplejs.create({\n        zone: document.getElementById('zone_joystick'),\n        mode: 'semi',\n        catchDistance: 150,\n        color: 'white'\n    });\n\t\n\n\tsemi.on('move', function(evt, nipple_obj) {\n\t   debug(nipple_obj);\n\t});\n\t\n\t}\n\nfunction debug(obj) {\n  setTimeout(function() {\n    var test = obj.position.x;\n    console.log(test);\n  }, 0);\n}\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\n</script>","storeOutMessages":true,"fwdInMessages":true,"templateScope":"local","x":286,"y":708,"wires":[["17f18c51.494204","3e99bf46.a8532"]]},{"id":"b2219879.075b28","type":"inject","z":"9738c4ac.01e748","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":117,"y":675,"wires":[["ff5f827f.796e"]]},{"id":"17f18c51.494204","type":"ui_text","z":"9738c4ac.01e748","group":"9550e4e.ea6f618","order":0,"width":"3","height":"2","name":"","label":"text","format":"{{msg.payload}}","layout":"row-spread","x":468,"y":736,"wires":[]},{"id":"3e99bf46.a8532","type":"debug","z":"9738c4ac.01e748","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":314,"y":769,"wires":[]},{"id":"9550e4e.ea6f618","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Joystick","tab":"ccfc45fa.de7cb8","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"ccfc45fa.de7cb8","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Bubbles","icon":"dashboard"}]
```

For those who don't want to import the flow, here is the Script I use. As you see in function debug, I can print the values to console. I need this value back.

```js
<script src="/myjs/nippleJS/nipplejs.min.js" ></script>

<div data-type="semi" id="zone_joystick" style="position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:grey;"></div>

<script>


           (function(scope){ 

                scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
                createJoystick();
           
                });
            })(scope);


function createJoystick(){
    var semi = nipplejs.create({
        zone: document.getElementById('zone_joystick'),
        mode: 'semi',
        catchDistance: 150,
        color: 'white'
    });
 

 semi.on('move', function(evt, nipple_obj) {
    debug(nipple_obj);
    
 });
 
 }

function debug(obj) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var test = obj.position.x;
    console.log(test);
  }, 0);
} 
 
  

</script>
```

Thank you for your support, Patrick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scope` object has a `send` function that can be used to send a message from the `ui_template` node within the runtime.

You need to structure your code so the callback for the `move` event is in scope of the `scope` variable. For example, replace your code inside the `<script>` block with:

```
(function(scope){ 

    function createJoystick(){
        var semi = nipplejs.create({
            zone: document.getElementById('zone_joystick'),
            mode: 'semi',
            catchDistance: 150,
            color: 'white'
        });
        semi.on('move', function(evt, nipple_obj) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var test = obj.position.x;
                // use scope.send to trigger a message in the runtime flow
                scope.send({payload:test});
            }, 0);

        });
    }


    scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
        createJoystick();

    });
})(scope);
```

Comment: Just for the case someone else want to use nippleJS on node-red dashbard, here my flows

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else wants to use nippleJS, here is my workling code

```
[{"id":"d1cb92a5.0e9b2","type":"inject","z":"cf477024.84de6","name":"Trigger UI Templates","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":163,"y":209,"wires":[["93a7c595.e3b868","8b092d1b.0e2ed"]]},{"id":"8b092d1b.0e2ed","type":"ui_template","z":"cf477024.84de6","group":"52892a0c.d9c5b4","name":"Joystick","order":0,"width":"6","height":"6","format":"<script src=\"/myjs/nippleJS/nipplejs.min.js\" ></script>\n\n<div data-type=\"dynamic\" id=\"zone_joystick\" style=\"position:absolute; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:grey;\"></div>\n\n<script>\n\n\n(function(scope){ \n\n    function createJoystick(){\n        var dynamic = nipplejs.create({\n            zone: document.getElementById('zone_joystick'),\n            mode: 'dynamic',\n            catchDistance: 150,\n            color: 'white'\n        });\n        dynamic.on('move', function(evt, nipple_obj) {\n            setTimeout(function() {\n                var posx = nipple_obj.position.x;\n                var posy = nipple_obj.position.y;\n                var centerx = nipple_obj.instance.position.x;\n                var centery = nipple_obj.instance.position.y;\n                // use scope.send to trigger a message in the runtime flow\n                scope.send({payload:{x: posx, y:posy, centerx:centerx, centery:centery}});\n            }, 0);\n\n        });\n    }\n\n\n    scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {\n        createJoystick();\n\n    });\n})(scope);\n\n</script>","storeOutMessages":false,"fwdInMessages":false,"templateScope":"local","x":434,"y":212,"wires":[["65da6852.c65ac8","fbdf3963.9c2858"]]},{"id":"fbdf3963.9c2858","type":"function","z":"cf477024.84de6","name":"","func":"\nvar x = {payload:msg.payload.centerx - msg.payload.x};\nvar y = {payload:msg.payload.centery - msg.payload.y};\n\nreturn [x, y];","outputs":2,"noerr":0,"x":578,"y":216,"wires":[["26f05e22.8d3a12"],["2d78681b.d82be8"]]},{"id":"26f05e22.8d3a12","type":"ui_text","z":"cf477024.84de6","group":"52892a0c.d9c5b4","order":0,"width":"3","height":"1","name":"","label":"X","format":"{{msg.payload}}","layout":"row-spread","x":710,"y":227,"wires":[]},{"id":"2d78681b.d82be8","type":"ui_text","z":"cf477024.84de6","group":"52892a0c.d9c5b4","order":0,"width":"3","height":"2","name":"","label":"Y","format":"{{msg.payload}}","layout":"row-spread","x":719,"y":275,"wires":[]},{"id":"65da6852.c65ac8","type":"debug","z":"cf477024.84de6","name":"","active":false,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","x":571,"y":257,"wires":[]},{"id":"52892a0c.d9c5b4","type":"ui_group","z":"","name":"Default","tab":"56c2703a.7a819","disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"56c2703a.7a819","type":"ui_tab","z":"","name":"Manual","icon":"dashboard"}]
```

Thanks again knolleary